# Rollback complete batch process

Tags: apex, batch, exception, rollback

I want to roll back a complete batch related transaction if there is any exception while processing anywhere during batch execution

I can roll back that specific transaction, but not sure if I can rollback complete batch process.

Thanks,

Ray

Answer (score 0):

If you don't catch exceptions or handle exceptions and use DML statements without partial DML like database.update your whole transaction by default will roll back when there is failure.

If you want to roll back previous batches,keep a flag or an identifier and in catch block just reverse the operation.

Update

An example could be to update the flag.In the finish method you can uncheck the flag to unmark all.

Comment: I think "reverse the operation" merits the caution that it may not be easy to do and maybe an example.

Comment: Hey Mohit, by reversing the operation do you mean undo all the processes that I have already done in previous batches? As that is going to be very complicated and will not be feasible.
I am more thinking around doind a proper rollback to an initial save point if possible

Comment: Kaushik do you want to revert whole process or a specific batch only .If specific batch as already mentioned just throw the exception so that salesforce dont commit anything .Thanks